# How to trigger CSS animation on View/Scroll?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have this simple code of an animated line graph. The animation works well but it starts on page load. I want it to start when the section is in the screen of the viewer/when the viewer scrolls to that section of the page.

If it needs other code like JS. Please tell me. Thank you!

Here are the HTML and CSS codes. And here is a [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/ANGEWO/pen/abyJPgB)

HTML:

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h3>Papua New Guinea</h3>
    <br>
    <p>Papua New Guinea is one of the most culturally diverse countries in the world.
      As of 2019, it is also the most rural, as only 13.25% of its people live in urban centres.
      Most of the
      population of more than 8,000,000 people live in customary communities, which are as diverse
      as the languages.</p>
    <h5>Living in Urban communities</h5>
    <div class="line line1">13.25%</div>
    <h5>Living in Customary Communities</h5>
    <div class="line line2">86.75</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper h3 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.wrapper h5 {
  text-align: left;
}

.line {
  height: 25px;
  min-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.line:before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  background: #d2d6d7;
}

.line:after {
  content: "";
  background: #333;
  height: 25px;
  transition: 0, 8s;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  animation: animate 1 4s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.line1:after {
  max-width: 13.25%;
}

.line2:after {
  max-width: 86.75%;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0% {
    width: 0;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes you will need some JS. Investigate IntersectionObserver, that will tell you when the bit you want to animate comes into the viewport. Also perhaps you could add the javascript tag to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animation-delay, but this not help you. You can use the JS code and track an event. This is code for example:

```js
var $win = $(window);
var $marker = $('#marker');
$win.scroll(function() {
    if ($win.scrollTop() + $win.height() >= $marker.offset().top) {
        $win.unbind('scroll');
        // load there
    }
});
```

Comment: How to use the JS file? Do I just paste it?

Comment: You have to add it to your website code, either with a separate .js file or directly in your HTML code using the `<script>` tag.